# Textbox into Label

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a program that whenever you type a letter in the textbox the number of the letter in alphabet would appear in the label...... I've tried some codes like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string userInput = textBox1.Text;            //get string from textbox
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput)) return;  //return if string is empty
    char c = char.ToUpper(userInput[userInput.Length - 1]); //get last char of string and normalize it to big letter
    int alPos = c-'A'+1;                         //subtract from char first alphabet letter

    label1 = alPos.ToString();    
}
```

and i want a program like this

[image]

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: your question should be more Specific and clear

Comment: Your code seems to be working, what is the question ?

Comment: I don't know how to run that code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `label1` is a Label That you placed in the UI, And you are trying to assign a string value to that control. Such assignment is not valid and not permitted. Your requirement is to assign `alPos` as the Text property of the Label Control. So your query should be like the following:

```
label1.Text = alPos.ToString();
```

Comment: OMGYGOD Thanks ! i dont know how could i thank you for this :( ! 
i really appreciated